# How do degrees work in Ukraine?

Tags: education, ukraine

How many years are needed for obtaining a degree in Ukraine? Are there bachelor's degree (3-4 years) and master's degrees (2 years) if you want to continue?

Comment: This is a question more about how an education system works, there's no real relation stated to things being any different for you due to being an expat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system has changed since last I looked at the college education in Ukraine.  But it would be better to check directly with a particular institution in Ukraine to determine the length.

For example [ХНУРЭ](http://nure.ua/supply/admissions-committee/informaciya-abiturientu/) (Russian) states that they have a 4 year bachelor program, additional 1 year "specialist" or 1.5 years for "magister" or equivalent of US Masters program. So does the [Kharkov Aerospace University](http://www.khai.edu/efc/course/k103.html) but other universities may have different requirement or program lengths(though unlikely).

Comment: Is it true that the university there starts at 16 years?

Comment: @Revious Not any more.  During the Soviet times the school education was 10 years so from 7-17.  Which means that you could enter the University at 17, which I did back in the day.  The current system is 12 year so it's 18 at the earliest.

Comment: Nope.  And I don't think it would matter today.

Answer (score 3):

Ukraine has apparently taken steps to become consistent with the [Bologna Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process), so if you are familiar with that, it means most universities will likely offer Bachelors and Masters programs, if not now, then in the near future.

It might not be consistent yet across all institutions, so if you are thinking of a particular university, I would recommend looking at what they have to offer directly.